# How can I calculate the number of degrees of freedom in the Elastic Net regularization, specifically in R?

Tags: r, regularization, glmnet, degrees-of-freedom, elastic-net

In the elastic net, and specifically in `glment` package in R - how would I obtain the number of degrees of freedom? Note that in the [Glmnet Vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) it says that the `df` you get from the ouput after an Elastic Net model is the number of effective degrees of freedom for the LASSO! I'm using elastic net with `alpha = 0.5`, so the question is what do I use for the degrees of freedom? (I need that to compute AIC manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is here:

[image]

This is from a talk by Hui Zou. You can find the full talk [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf).

This should be relatively easy to implement in R. If you need some guidance, you can check the [lassovar](https://github.com/lcallot/lassovar) package by A. Kock and L. Callot; see the command **.ridge.df** in [lassovar-ada.R](https://github.com/lcallot/lassovar/blob/master/R/lassovar-ada.R).

*Related reference:*

Zou, H., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2007). On the "degrees of freedom" of the lasso. Ann. Statist., 35(5), 2173–2192. https://doi.org/10.1214/009053607000000127  -- *This is the formal proof that df of the lasso = number of non-zero coefficients of the lasso.*

Comment: If this is the correct formula, I was wondering why glmnet is just returning the nr of nonzero coefficients as $df though. Would anyone know?

Comment: I suppose returning the effective df would be computationally costly as it requires one matrix inversion per lambda. Also, the focus of glmnet is on cross-validation rather than tuning parameter selection via information criteria (for which df are relevant).

Comment: Is this the true active set or the estimated active set? Using the true active set would make the estimator infeasible, so I suppose we have the estimated one here.