# Finding the F statistic of an ANN regression model

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am using the `neuralnet` package in R, and I wish to find out the F-statistic of a model for a particular regression fit.

I have gone through this [link](https://vitalflux.com/interpreting-f-statistics-in-linear-regression-formula-examples/), where they tell you the method to find the F - statistic for a linear regression.

For a neural network, the training and test data are first separated. Subsequently, the training is conducted on the training data and then the prediction error is calculated from the test data.

Here, what would be the number of the coefficients (or the degree of freedom)? How do I calculate or find out the degree of freedom, in order for me to find the F-statistic?

---

Edit: I strongly believe that the system which is use to collect the data, has a strong influence on how a model behaves. I am working on Machining (Lathe CNC Machining) data. According to several papers that I have found on ScienceDirect, there is a strong influence of the type of material used and the method of machining. The most significant variable (explanatory) is different for each type of material.

Comment: What for? It's [not obvious](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/444014/35989) how to define degrees of freedom for neural networks and you *can have* more parameters than data points, what would lead to invalid, negative degrees of freedom for the F-distribution.

Comment: Saw your post. However, data dynamics play a different role. Of course, I have not mentioned it, but I am dealing with machining data, and the MNIST database is a different kind of dataset. Therefore, I cannot make sure if the paper cited therein have any impact on my kind of dataset.

Edit: See [here][https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06021]

Comment: What does MNIST have to do with anything?

Comment: May I request you to kindly refer to the post that @Tim was referring to, and the paper posted therein?

Comment: I think we need some more background on your problem.  What is your intended goal?  Why do you think a neural net is a good tool for this?  For what reason are you interested in conducting an F test; what do you think it provides you with?

Comment: For the explanatory and predictor variables, I have tried all the mechanisms of linear regression, including the interaction models (from full to partial). However, I do not think that the behavior of the system is linear, per se (given the graphs I get). As a result, I would like to use the Neural Networks for model fitting.

Comment: @Indian And what would an F-stat tell you?

Comment: https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/interpret-f-test-overall-significance-regression/

Comment: @SuddhasheelGhosh Do you want to know if the neural network gives better predictions than an intercept-only model? If not, please say why you want an F-statistic.

Comment: Can you post evidence that the outcome can not be sufficiently modelled with linear regression?  Remember, the "linear" in linear regression means that the prediction is a linear combination of the columns.  Should those columns be non-linear functions (e.g. splines) then you can model non-linear relationships with linear regression.

Comment: While comparing various linear regression models with full and partial interactions, we found that the indicators of performances R^2, Adj - R^2, AIC, BIC, log-Likelihood, F-statistic and corresponding p-Value were not behaving the same way. For example, the least AIC did not have the largest R^2. Therefore, we decided to use NN. However, how do we compare? We need the same measures or standards for comparison!

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes, unfortunately, I do know what linear means in Linear Regression! In complete naivete, one would remark that the system is able to translate itself into a set of linear simultaneous equations, which can be solved by any of the Gaussian methods.

Comment: *"While comparing various linear regression models with full and partial interactions, we found that the indicators of performances R^2, Adj - R^2, AIC, BIC, log-Likelihood, F-statistic and corresponding p-Value were not behaving the same way"* -That's not a reasonable justification to use an NN. All these statistics are supposed to not follow the same trend (otherwise, why would we need them all?). F depends on R² and degrees of freedom, p depends on F and degrees of freedom, AIC depends on degrees of freedom and the negative loglikelihood, R² depends on the negative log-likelihood, etc, etc.

Comment: Also, if you hypothetically could extract the F-statistic of a Neural Network, how would that solve your problem? It's just one more model, one more statistic

Comment: @Firebug Just another statistic, is not an answer to "How do I chose the best model?"

Comment: It's not an answer for "How do I chose the best model?" because that is not the question. The question is clearly: "How do I calculate or find out the degree of freedom, in order for me to find the F-statistic?"

Answer (score 2):

*There was an extended discussion in the comments that surfaced some misconceptions, so I'll address them in the answer as it’d probability answer the question.*

> For the explanatory and predictor variables, I have tried all the mechanisms of linear regression, including the interaction models (from full to partial). However, I do not think that the behavior of the system is linear, per se (given the graphs I get). As a result, I would like to use the Neural Networks for model fitting.

You didn't exhaust the possibilities of extending the linear regression model. You could add polynomial features or other data transmissions, to model non-linear relations. Moreover, there are many other machine learning models between linear regression and neural networks, so jumping straight to neural networks seems a bit fast.

> While comparing various linear regression models with full and partial interactions, we found that the indicators of performances R^2, Adj - R^2, AIC, BIC, log-Likelihood, F-statistic and corresponding p-Value were not behaving the same way. For example, the least AIC did not have the largest R^2.

So what? It's not surprising to see different metrics giving different results because they measure different things. If all the metrics gave the same results all the time, there wouldn't be any reason to have more than one metric. It has *nothing* to do with the relationship being non-linear.

It's not clear at all why you want to use the $F$-test here. It is not a measure of goodness of fit, but a hypothesis test. As noticed in the comment by Dave, it tests the hypothesis if your model is better than the intercept-only model, i.e. predicting the mean for all the cases. I don't see how testing if a neural network behaves better than predicting a constant made any sense. Sure, it's a good benchmark to make sure that your predictions are not complete rubbish, but you can verify that by comparing some metrics for predicting mean vs another model on a held-out test set to verify that.

Finally, as I noticed in the comment it's not clear how would we define the degrees of freedom for neural networks (or many other machine learning models). I [linked to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/intuitive-explanation-of-the-bias-variance-tradeoff/444014#444014) a thread that discusses that and provides some papers digging deeper into the subject. For example, neural networks *can have* more parameters than there are samples in data, so the $n-p$ in $F$-test would get negative (invalid), and the number of parameters is not even a good measure of the degrees of freedom, as they interact with each other.

So it doesn't seem that you need the $F$-test, it wouldn't make much sense in here, and there is no meaningful way to calculate it. From what you described, it is not even necessarily true that there is something “wrong” with your predictions, or that it can't be solved with linear regression.

Comment: I believe that the misconception is on your side. An engineer would rather prefer to use an empirical model established in the literature, rather than go for the naive trial-and-error approach that you are hinting at. In the absence of empirical models, the trial and error approach is pretty dangerous, as engineering has several social implications. 

In my opinion and observation, your answer purely focuses on theoretical rigor which in a way is good but ignores system dynamics. Further, the thread you point to, talks about classification, but I am strictly talking about regression.

Comment: @SuddhasheelGhosh I said nothing about the trial-and-error approach. The linked thread uses classification as an example but also applies also to regression. Also, I don't understand how using neural networks relates to the "empirical model established in the literature" and how system dynamics has anything to do with what is discussed here.

Comment: "You didn't exhaust the possibilities of extending the linear regression model. You could add polynomial features or other data transmissions, to model non-linear relations. Moreover, there are many other machine learning models between linear regression and neural networks, so jumping straight to neural networks seems a bit fast." - is hinting at a trial-and-error approach.

Comment: @SuddhasheelGhosh how exactly does it differ from using a neural network that would do the feature engineering for you..? A neural network is a universal approximation, so it can produce *any* function, including polynomials and even more crazy transformations.

Comment: *I'm backing off the discussion, since I already answered your question and don't have much more to add.*

Comment: That is sad because the question was "How do I find the F statistic?" and the discussion summary, from your end, was "You don't need it!". No, I need it.

Comment: @SuddhasheelGhosh you are going to shoot yourself in a foot and it gonna hurt.

Answer (score 2):

**During training** a NN is often overparameterised and only fits well because of some explicit or implicit regularisation. To compute the effective degrees of freedom is very difficult. With elastic net ([How can I calculate the number of degrees of freedom in the Elastic Net regularization, specifically in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327088/)) there is a method that approximates the effective degree of freedom by using the [hat matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) which expresses the 'flexibility'/variation of the model around the final fitted point. I wouldn't be surprised if equivalent approaches exist for neural networks.

**After training** a model you have a fixed formula for predictions. Which contains zero parameters. If you test it then there is no parameter fitting anymore. So your F statistic will use the same degrees of freedom in numerator and denominator and the statistic resembles a [relative likelihood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_likelihood).

Sidenote: the use of a F-statistic is not very rigorous in this case. Assumptions relating to it's use are independent and identical normal distributed error terms. So theoretical calculations that estimate statistical probabilities, like p-values, are likely wrong. The use of the F-statistic makes more sense when you can apply some statistical model for it's sample distribution. Otherwise it is just a random measure. Maybe you could better use a more intuitive measure like comparing some relevant cost function.

Related: [What does "degree of freedom" mean in neural networks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57027/)